# Qt combobox crash

Tags: c++, qt, vector, combobox, crash

I found out that second for loop is crashing my app and I have no idea why

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rejestr::wektor_filmy.size(); i++) {
        ui->comboBox->addItem(QString::fromStdString(Rejestr::wektor_filmy[i].tytul));
    }

for (int i = 0; i < Rejestr::wektor_filmy[ui->comboBox->currentIndex()].seanse.size(); i++)
{
        ui->comboBox_2->addItem(QString::number(Rejestr::wektor_filmy[ui->comboBox->currentIndex()].seanse[i].godzina));
}
```

I want second combobox to display data depending on the first combobox

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
if (Rejestr::wektor_filmy.size() > 0)
```

before second for loop, that's all

Comment: if this indeed solves your problem you should accept this answer to make it clear to others that your problem is solved